# jQuery selector (from within a plugin) works in jsFiddle, but not real page?

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

For the life of me, I can't figure out why trying to select an element via the jQuery global object works in jsFiddle, but not on a normal page.

[HTML](https://gist.github.com/2764435)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3x69/1/)

I've been wrestling with this problem for some time building a larger plugin, and eventually narrowed it down to this weird discrepancy.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: @gdoron what's wrong with it?

Comment: @gdoron, can you explain how you think a plugin should be made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because on your page you are not waiting for the DOM to be ready before running `$.salsaform();`.

jsFiddle has your code in an `onLoad` handler, so it runs once the DOM is ready.

Change your script to this:

```
(function ($) {
  $.salsaform = function () {
    console.log($('#foo'));
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function(){
    $.salsaform();
});
```

The `$(function(){...})` runs your code after the DOM is ready.

Comment: @gdoron: What are you talking about?

Comment: @gdoron: I'd say it depends on what you're trying to do (for example: `$.cookie`).

Comment: @gdoron - Using `$.fn.myplugin` vs `$.myplugin` define two different (not wrong!) types of plugins that have different purposes. If you need a plugin that doesn't directly interact with any specific element, it wouldn't make sense to define it on `$.fn`

Comment: @gdoron writing a plugin is not in the context of this question

Comment: Thank you! So obvious, I can't believe I didn't remember that.

Comment: @gdoron Yeah, a selector here wouldn't have been useful as this plugin can't be applied to multiple elements on a page.